# simple python loop that makes a new line once it reads a new value

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python. I am trying to apply a loop over a sorted list. the idea is whenever the loop reads a new value different from the previous one it makes a new line before it (the editor I am using is jupyter notebook)
what I've tried is

```
d=[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5]
for i in d:
  if i == d[i]:
     print(i)
  elif i != d[i]:
     print(i)
     print('\n')
```

The expected output should be something like this

```
1
1
1
*new line*
2
2
*new line*
3
*new line*
4
*new line*
5
5
5
```

but unfortunately this code didn't do the job. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current number isn't equal to previous one, print a new line before printing the item.

```
d=[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5]

for i in range(len(d)):
  if i > 0 and d[i] != d [i - 1]:
      print('\n')
  print(d[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do that by comparing the elements in the sorted list, as follows:

```
d=[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5]
for i in range(len(d)-1):
   if d[i] == d[i+1]:
     print(d[i])
   else:
     print(d[i])
     print('\n')
print(d[i])
```

**Output:**

```
1
1
1

2
2

3

4

5
5
5
```

Comment: This doesn't print the last value in the array.

Comment: @tdurnford Thanks for the hint. I added another line to print out the last element

Comment: That's one solution. I would recommend looking at the range your iterating over and adjusting the logic in your if statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a `last` var to keep track and iterate over your list, only printing a newline when the element differs from `last`

```py
last = d[0]
for element in d:
   if element!=last:
      print('\n')
   last = element
   print(element)
```

Output

```py
1
1
1

2
2

3

4

5
5
5
```

Answer (score 1):

More fancy; [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

d = [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5]

for _, y in groupby(d):
    print('\n'.join(map(str, y)), end='\n\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

With your code, you are using `i` to iterate through the array `d` but then using `i` to access the element of the array `d[i]` thus `i == d[i]` will be true for the first three iterations then after that it'll be false (e.g. `i = 2`, `d[2] = 1`, therefore `(i == d[i]) == False`. Also, no need for an `elif` clause since you are only worried about one case. Use a variable to keep track of the previous element in the array and that should do the trick.

```
d=[1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5]
temp = d[0]
for i in d:
  if temp != i:
     print('\n')
  print(i)
  temp = i
```

Edit: sorry read the code wrong, explanation should be better now